# unable to export 5000 rows

Tags: asp.net

I want to export  5000 rows using Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel to excel sheet.There is no error shown but the excel sheet is not getting generated

Comment: If you save the download, do you get anything at all? I suggest you start with that, then look at the saved file to see if you can spot anything wrong. If you're not getting anything, then debugging is the way to go.

Comment: I have done that but i'm not getting the excel sheet at all once the records are above 5000

Comment: Have you tried generating and saving the document on the server then downloading it? That might give you some insight into what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark: is it possible that your page is timing out when you have that large number of records? You could try upping the page timeout by setting the following in your Page_Init:

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 600
```

This sets the timeout to 10 minutes (the default is 90 seconds).

Answer (score 1):

Chances are good that the amount of time it takes to generate your spreadsheet exceeds the timeout period allowed for code to finish executing during a response.

One way around this is to have the code that generates the spreadsheets running as a totally separate process that acts a service.  Users can then use your main asp.net application to start the process and monitor its progress each time they refresh the page.  Once the process is complete, the next time they refresh, a link to download the generated spreadsheet should be displayed.

This method can be further enhanced with some simple AJAX that polls the server every 10 seconds or so to update the progress indicator on the client and display the download link when its finished.