# Unable to export more than 5000 rows in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I did an app to export all my policies in a excel file but is not exporting all my information

Here is the query in mysql

```
select * from policies where deleted = 0 AND (state = 0 OR state= 1) ORDER BY state ASC 
i got 11,408 total when i executed it on mysql
```

Here is my controller

```
  @search = Policy.find_by_sql("select * from policies where deleted = 0 AND (state = 0 OR state= 1) ORDER BY state ASC ")
  @policies = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  @results = @search

  respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.xls { send_data render_to_string(:partial=>"report"), :filename => "Report.xls" }
  end
```

Here is my view

```
 <%= link_to "Export Excel",{:controller=>"policy",:action=>"report", :format=>"xls",:page => params[:page] }  %>
```

Here is my partial view

```
<% @results.each do |policy| %>
     <%= policy.num_policy %> 
<% end %>
```

Actually is only exporting 5078 rows and i should have 11,408

Someone can help me with this?

I will really appreciate help

Here is my last log

```
 Rendered policy_management/policy/_report_by_ejecutive (42929.2ms)
 Sending data Report_2013-11-11.xls
 Completed in 43533ms (View: 0, DB: 0) | 200 OK [http://0.0.0.0/policy_management/policy/generate_print_ejecutive?format=xls]
```

Comment: I recall method includes pagination [sql-limit], at one time I had a problem similar nature. Review your sql query and pagination.

Comment: My query is working in mysql,well i put border 0 to check if the border is closed on the 5000 row but is not border, i checked at the end at 11000 row and it closed , what is wrong seems that it has a limit, someone had the same problem?

Comment: I found this but is for asp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403884/unable-to-export-5000-rows/1404046?noredirect=1#comment29393982_1404046

Comment: @CarlitosMorales you should post your server log. If it is a timeout problem, it will show. If it is an ActiveRecord problem with generating the SQL, it will also show. Timeout depends on your server conf, so you might as well tell what environment you're working with (heroku, for instance, enforces a relatively short timeout time to encourage using workers)

Comment: okey i posted my last log

Comment: what happen when you remove pagination? so only `@policies = @search`

Comment: It exports only 5000 rows but i should have 11000 rows that's the problem.

Comment: What is the result of `@search.count`? Also, do you have a default_scope on Policy? Or using any plugins/gems/unusual stuff in Policy or in general?

Comment: Also, check that your rails app is querying the same database that you connected to in the mysql console. Also, you could try `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all('select .........')` as a test.

Comment: i used ".count" and got  11,408

Comment: How can i do ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all('select .........') as a test ???? where is that?

Comment: @Carlitos - my select_all suggestion is probably no longer needed - it was an alternate way of querying, in case ActiveRecord was filtering behind the scenes, but since you are getting the expected 11408 records, it looks like an export problem rather than an ActiveRecord problem.

Comment: Maybe take a look at which rows are exported and which aren't. Is it exporting the _first_ 5078 records or is it going through them all and skipping certain ones? Maybe in some records num_policy is blank or null or some "bad" value that's not showing up? (I'm just guessing but those are the sorts of things I'd start looking at...)

Comment: Yes i thought that there were NUll values but i have values and is not exporting . I tried <% @results.find_each(:batch_size => 1000) do |policy| %>
 <%= policy.num_policy %> 
<% end %>..................but i got i got "undefined method `find_each' i feel that is the answer but is not working find_each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use batch query
[ActiveRecord Batch query](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches)

@search = Policy.find_by_sql("select * from policies where deleted = 0 AND (state = 0 OR state= 1) ORDER BY state ASC ")

```
@search = Policy.where("deleted = 0 AND (state = 0 OR state = 1)").order("state ASC")
```

In your partial

```
<% @results.find_each(:batch_size => 1000) do |policy| %>
 <%= policy.num_policy %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried your code but i'm using rails 2.3
compile error
/home/carlos/proyectos/company/app/views/policy_management/policy/_report_by_ejecutive.erb:27: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
...@results.find_each(batch_size: 1000) do |policy| ; @output_b...
                              ^
/home/carlos/proyectos/company/app/views/policy_management/policy/_report_by_ejecutive.erb:68: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end

Comment: oops, are you using ruby < 1.9 ? then you must use :batch_size => 1000. please read my updated answer

Comment: I tried your code and now i got "undefined method `find_each' for #<Array:0x7f102da9b2a0> "

Answer (score 3):

It could be because you're paginating the results (which applies a scope on the larger result set). Can you try removing the pagination?

Comment: @CarlitosMorales The pagination doesn't order the results - It just gives you enough results for each page (which makes sense for the web but not for csv exports). The ordering is handled by your SQL `ORDER BY state ASC`. Please update the question with pagination removed - there is probably a reference to it left either in the view or controller.

Comment: Can you try removing `:page => params[:page]` from `link_to Export Excel`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to narrow down where the issue lies.

For example, you haven't mentioned if the limitation only happens when generating the Excel format. How many rows do you get when requesting the page in HTML format?

You can also check how many objects are created from the query by going to the console and doing this:

```
@search = Policy.find_by_sql("select * from policies where deleted = 0 AND (state = 0 OR state= 1) ORDER BY state ASC ")
puts @search.count
```

and check the log what number it outputs.

Next check the log . It will show you what database query is actually executed. If there is a pagination gem or some configuration would be influencing the outcome, then you'd see a different sql query that is actually executed.

Answer (score 1):

have you try return csv record first? i think maybe this is relative to the excel exporter, there maybe a limit on how many records in a single excel sheet.

Comment: I didn't return csv but seems that could be the time that takes exporting